# How get type of instance of Object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get type of instance of object in Typescript, so far I got this (below). Is it any way to write it in one line? Surprisingly, I cannot find anything about it in web/google

```
const inst = new Matrix4();
type Matrix4 = typeof inst;
```

Comment: `type Matrix4 = InstanceType<typeof Matrix4>`?  What is your use case

Comment: @jcalz doesnt work, i get type any

Comment: I get type `any` on your code also.  You should consider editing your code to constitute a [mcve] so that others can reproduce your issue and help you.  Right now, the constructor `Matrix4` is not defined anywhere in your code.  Where is it coming from?

Comment: @jcals you right, but `Matrix4` imported from library, so can't get you code. It's come with [book](https://sites.google.com/site/webglbook/).

Comment: @jcalz ...defined with [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/), it's `js`

Comment: what you have written seems to throw an error in typescript (see [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Matrix4%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aconst%20inst%20%3D%20new%20Matrix4()%0Atype%20Matrix4%20%3D%20Matrix4%0A))

Comment: @zhirzh I cannot past library code here, cause then I get error, that "most of my question is code"

Comment: you can paste in [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) and share it

Comment: I suggest you try to produce a [mcve], which might mean trimming down the library code you are depending on to just whatever's necessary to reproduce your problem.  This is likely to be a lot shorter than just pasting library code here.  Or, if your question depends on a particular library and you can't trim it down, then consider adding tags to the question specifying this library so that others who know about it can make a suggestion.  Good luck!